# java Reflect Modifiers parameters

Tags: java, reflection, parameters

I declared a simple class with this method amongst others :

```
public void setDate(final Date date);
```

when i get the parameters :

```
List<Class<?>> params = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
params.addAll(Arrays.asList(method.getParameterTypes()));
```

I verify that it is final :

```
System.out.println("isFinal : " + Modifier.isFinal(params.get(0).getModifiers()));
```

But i get a false :

```
isFinal : false
```

But clearly i declared it to be final. What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `params.get(0)` returns a type (class) of parameter. In your case it is `java.util.Date` which is **not** final.

It is not possible use reflection to find out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Really, it's impossible ? so the reflection has limitations ?  OK I remove this validation test then.

Answer (score 4):

You're asking whether the *type* is `final`, not the *parameter* - and `java.util.Date` isn't a final class.

Looking at the API, I can't immediately see any way of determining that a parameter is final - but that's really an implementation detail anyway. It makes no difference to the caller at all.